k8s CRD definition: 4 mutually exclusive optional fields
I have created a CRD for a resource and currently unable to make them mutually exclusive and optional at the same time:
optionOne:
  type: string
optionTwo:
  type: string
optionThree:
  type: string
optionFour:
  type: string

How to combine exclusitivity and optionality of these fields?
I tried using
oneOf:
- not:
    required: ["optionOne"]

But it didn't work.

Please revise your question to include a minimal repro of your issue. "it didn't work" is insufficient. Please show what you did, what happened and what you expected to happen.

Are you trying to put this into the OpenAPI schema in a CustomResourceDefinition, or somewhere else?  Are you using a framework like Kubebuilder to generate the CustomResourceDefinition object?  To be clear, you want at most one of those options; none is okay, but two is right out?

@DavidMaze, yes, I want to put it into OpenAPI schema in CRD. The idea is to make them optional, but only one of them can be set in the manifest.

I used Rust and kube-derive to define a FourOption type that takes an optional oneOf value. It generated the following CRD:
fouroption.crd.yaml:
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: fouroptions.example.com
spec:
  group: example.com
  names:
    categories: []
    kind: FourOption
    plural: fouroptions
    shortNames: []
    singular: fouroption
  scope: Namespaced
  versions:
  - additionalPrinterColumns: []
    name: v1alpha1
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        description: Stackoverflow 78523396
        properties:
          spec:
            properties:
              foo:
                nullable: true
                oneOf:
                - required:
                  - option_one
                - required:
                  - option_two
                - required:
                  - option_three
                - required:
                  - option_four
                properties:
                  option_four:
                    type: string
                  option_one:
                    type: string
                  option_three:
                    type: string
                  option_two:
                    type: string
                type: object
            type: object
        required:
        - spec
        title: FourOption
        type: object
    served: true
    storage: true
    subresources: {}

NAMESPACE="78523396"
kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE}

kubectl apply --filename=./fouroption.crd.yaml

customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/fouroptions.example.com configured

Then I tested with none; oneof; and multiple:
kind: List
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
items:
# Expect: succeed
- kind: FourOption
  apiVersion: example.com/v1alpha1
  metadata:
    name: none
  spec:
    foo: null
# Expect: succeed
- kind: FourOption
  apiVersion: example.com/v1alpha1
  metadata:
    name: option-two
  spec:
    foo:
      option_two: Hello Freddie
# Expect: fail
- kind: FourOption
  apiVersion: example.com/v1alpha1
  metadata:
    name: multiple
  spec:
    foo:
      option_two: Hello Freddie
      option_four: Hello Freddie

Yields:
fouroption.example.com/none created
fouroption.example.com/option-two created
The FourOption "multiple" is invalid: <nil>: Invalid value: "": "spec.foo" must validate one and only one schema (oneOf). Found 2 valid alternatives


Thank you, the addition of a new nullable section worked as a charm.

Awesome! I'm pleased to hear it. Thanks for the update.
